# PHP How to select and display a row from a mysql table after a user logs in

Tags: php

So I'm making a site that requires people to sign up and log in, and I was wondering how to display the user's info after they log in?

The code for my members area page (members.php) is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<?
session_start(); // the session variable in the login form is  $_SESSION['emailaddress']
?>


<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php

 echo "your email is... ".$_SESSION['emailaddress']; // i used only one session variable

 $user=$_SESSION['emailaddress'];


 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE email='$user'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . " " . $row['password'];   
  }

 ?>


</body>
</html>
```

However, when i go to the members page after I log in, it only displays the user's email address in the first echo (echo "your email is... ".$_SESSION['emailaddress'];). Is something wrong with the algorithm above used to select the user's data in the row?

Comment: why do you call session start not before any output?

Comment: Possibly your query does not return any rows if you don't get errors. Which means your email address you are searching for does not exist in the database.

Comment: hmm i just checked the database, and the email address does seem to be there >_<.

Answer (score 0):

The best workaround is to first print the query in the browser

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE email='$user'";
echo $query; 
$result = mysql_query($query);



$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . " " . $row['password'];    

 ?>
```

Btw, you don't need a while sentence loop when retrieving 1 row.

Once you get the query, copy it and run it directly on the database and check the results with MySQL GUI Tools or MySQL Workbench, I'm sure you will find the issue;

- Regards

Answer (score 0):

In the 14th line while executing the query you forgot to include connection with the database in the `$result`. See below.

```
$con=mysql_connect(hostname,username,password,databasename);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE email='$user'",$con);
```